# searching string containing special characters in mongodb using $regex

Tags: mongodb

I want to search the name `B&B Hôtel`  which contain some special charaters like & and ô by typing  `BB Hotel`

in my code I have this:

```
db.txt.find({ "name": {'$regex': query, $options:'i'}})
```

query may be name like that : `BB Hotel`

I have tried that code but it does not giving any thing, so any have an idea please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your text search requirement but I believe MongoDB does advise its user to use text indexing engine like ElasticSearch or Apache Solr for text searches.

If you still with to use Mongo, you can create a text index and set `$diacriticSensitive` to false. [$text documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)

```
{  
  $text:
    {
      $search: <string>,
      $language: <string>,
      $caseSensitive: <boolean>,
      $diacriticSensitive: <boolean>
    } 
}
```